# How to fetch a list of maps to a calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a response API here -

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "All the revisions of current user ",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "1",
            "revision_date": "2021-05-30",
            "revision_location": "gafsa",
            "revision_title": "Une visite technique est important avant le 30-05-2021",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "0",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-26",
            "revision_location": "tyyu",
            "revision_title": "ygyyii",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": 8655,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "2",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-20",
            "revision_location": "STAR",
            "revision_title": "Votre prochain renovellement de l'assurance sera le 20-06-2021 avec l'agence STAR",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": null
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "box_id": 31,
            "user_id": 53,
            "revision_type": "3",
            "revision_date": "2021-06-20",
            "revision_location": "sfax",
            "revision_title": "véhicule en panne",
            "kilometrage_pour_vidange": null,
            "repeat_revision": 0,
            "revision_status": 0,
            "kilometrage_last_vidange": null,
            "Kilometrage_revision": 87654
        }
    ],
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

I can show event already exist from my API to Table Calendar dynamically with no problem , All things work fine  . But I would like to display more than one variable on my card . At the moment i can display only  "revisionLocation" . How i can fecth other veriable to the screen

my code :

```
class _RevisionState extends State<Revision> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  //debut code events
  CalendarController _controller;
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  List<dynamic> _selectedEvents;
  TextEditingController _eventController, dateController;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  int status;
  bool _autovalidate = false;

  int status1 = 0;

//  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  RevisionApi revisionApi = RevisionApi();

  TextEditingController _Kilometrage_revisionController =
      TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController _KilometrageController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _EmplacementController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _DateController = TextEditingController();
  /* TextEditingController _repeat_revisionController =
      TextEditingController(text: "non");*/
  TextEditingController _revision_titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _revision_agenceController = TextEditingController();
//  TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getTask1().then((val) => setState(() {
            _events = val;
          }));
      //print( ' ${_events.toString()} ');
    });
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _eventController = TextEditingController();
    _events = {};
    initializeDateFormatting();
    _selectedEvents = [];
    prefsData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    // print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF050127),
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF010611),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              widget.title = 'Révision',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              //textHeightBehavior: ,
            ),
            elevation: 0.0,
            leading: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SideBar()));
              },
              child: Icon(CommunityMaterialIcons.segment),
            ),
            actions: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search, /*color: Colors.black87*/
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
            ]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    height: size.height * 0.05,
                    width: size.width * 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy       hh:mm:ss")
                              .format(DateTime.now()),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              letterSpacing: 1),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              CommunityMaterialIcons.calendar_plus,
                              color: KYellow,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _showAddDialog();
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: (_buildTableCalendarWithBuilders()),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              _buildEventList(),
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
_showAddDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: Text("Ajouter un évènement"),
              content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                StateSetter setState,
              ) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  //
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    autovalidate: _autovalidate,
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(children: [
                            Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hoverColor: Colors.white,
                                  /* contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 10, right: 15, top: 15),*/
                                  labelText: 'Type',
                                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                                value: status,
                                items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    // value: 'videnge',
                                    value: 0,

                                    child: InkWell(
                                      child: Text('Vidange'),
                                      hoverColor: Colors.indigo,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    // value: 'visite technique',
                                    value: 1,

                                    child: Text('Visite technique'),
                                  ),
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    //  value: 'assurance véhicule',
                                    value: 2,

                                    child: Text('Assurance véhicule'),
                                  ),
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    // value: 'autre',
                                    value: 3,

                                    child: Text('Autre'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    status = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            )),
                          ]),
                          if (status == 0) vidangeDropdown(),
                          if (status == 1) visiTechniqueDropdown(),
                          if (status == 2) assuranceDropdown(),
                          if (status == 3) autresDropdown(),

 actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Enregistrer",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_eventController.text.isEmpty == null) return;
                    setState(() {
                      if (_events[_controller.selectedDay] != null) {
                        _events[_controller.selectedDay]
                            .add(_eventController.text);
                      } else {
                        _events[_controller.selectedDay] = [
                          _eventController.text
                        ];
                      }
                      prefs.setString(
                          "events", json.encode(encodeMap(_events)));
                      _eventController.clear();
                      setRevision();

                      //   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      //   Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                    //  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Retour'),
                ),
              ],
            ));
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = _events[_controller.selectedDay];
    });
  }
    Widget _buildEventList() {
        return Column(children: [
          ..._selectedEvents.map(
            (event) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                CommunityMaterialIcons.oil,
                                color: KYellow,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                event,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: KYellow,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                              'Votre véhicule atteint 45 000 Km un vidange est important'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Dernier visite effectuée le 23/12/2020',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[400]),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  CommunityMaterialIcons.file_clock,
                                  size: 35,
                                  color: KYellow,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 30,
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  CommunityMaterialIcons.content_save_edit_outline,
                                  size: 35,
                                  color: KYellow,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (event == 'Vidange') {
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          _buildUpdateVidengeEvent(context),
                                    );
                                  } else
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          _buildUpdateEvent(context),
                                    );
                                },
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ))),
            ),
          )
        ]);
      }
    
      Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask1() async {
        Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};
        List<Datum> event = await revisionApi.getAllRevision();
        for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
          var createTime = DateTime(event[i].revisionDate.year,
              event[i].revisionDate.month, event[i].revisionDate.day);
          var original = mapFetch[createTime];
          if (original == null) {
            print("null");
            mapFetch[createTime] = [event[i].revisionLocation];
          } else {
            //  print(event[i].revisionLocation);
            mapFetch[createTime] = List.from(original)
              ..addAll([event[i].revisionLocation]);
          }
        }
        print(mapFetch);
        return mapFetch;
      }
    }
```

and this is the screen contain list of cards :

[image]

**I would like to add "revision_title" and "revision_date" instead static string in the body of the card . How i can do that ?**

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `selectedEvents` contain but if you want to use several parameters you should probably convert your data to a Dart class or a Map structure that encapsulates all the data required to build those widgets and use those parameters properly where needed.

From what the I see the `map` is for changing each element of the list into another one. If your events are the elements `[revision_location, revision_title]` you are actually building two widgets one with the first parameter and a second one with the second parameter. So if you want to display a single element you need to build a single widget with the elements at each index. And if you want to build several items you need to iterate through a `List<List>` or `List<Map>` or `List<DartClassWithData>` to fetch all data for each widget you build

➕ Also if for some reason the app becomes international you may consider using the intl official package to use `DateFormat` to format the dates according to each country, as long as it is local you may directly write the string you get the specific way you require.

I hope you find a solution and if you can't. At least add extra information about what problem you have fetching all the information inside a single encapsulated class .

Comment: I will add some code ... the problem will be clear

Comment: I think it's more clear now , can you help me ? . @Cavitedev

Comment: Your app is quite advanced and you are the main one who knows what you are using and how to solve it. You need some order on the `List<dynamic>`. Grasping all your project is an ordeal. If you can build a Widget from the Datum class or some other defined structure that would be better. You can learn which index stores what though that is not clean and hard to main

Comment: Right now the List<dynamic> is assumed to be storing String. But from what you are asking you need a `List<(class that contains revision_location, revision_title and revision_date)>`. I can't provide you with the code of a solution as I can't be sure to make it work. You just need to keep in mind that you are right now iterating through each element you want to display inside of the widget instead grasping all the elements in a widget

Comment: Do you want to display 1 or more widgets from the `_selectedEvents`?

Comment: i want to display more than one variable in the Widget _buildEventList() .At the moment i can only display event ( "revision_location") value . i want to add other variable in the same widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234194/discussion-between-lucky-and-cavitedev).